# Jquery ajax posting only some data at a time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have always used query ajax request to something simple like preventdefault form submit and adding beforesend function or complete function after the form is submitted like this to my nodejs backend:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/contact",
                beforeSend:function(){
                         $(".loading_msg").hide();

                    },
                complete:function(){
                         $(".loading_msg").show();
                         setTimeout(function(){
                             console.log('Here')
                            $(".loading_msg").fadeOut("slow");
                            $("#message").val("")
                         },3000)
                    } 
            });
```

Now, I have a sitution where I have to submit only part of the form input elements. There are also input elements inside the form which is dynamically generated.

Is there a way for me to send only input boxes with id's or classes that I want rather than the entire form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send some particular data to your server, you can config the `data` by yourself like the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/contact",
  data: {
    myKey1: $("#myKey1").val(),
    myKey2: $("#myKey2").val()
  },
  beforeSend:function(){
  $(".loading_msg").hide();

  },
  complete:function(){
   $(".loading_msg").show();
   setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Here')
    $(".loading_msg").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#message").val("")
   },3000)
  } 
});
```